# Prove that $ \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\phi(n)} $ exists or does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, totient-function

Prove that the limit exists or does not exist:

$$ \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\phi(n)}, $$

where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler Totient function.

The ratio test was inconclusive.

I'm fairly sure the p-series test says this series diverges because $p=1$ but then again in this case I'm not sure how to deal with a function in the place where $n$ normally is.

Comment: $\phi(n) \leq n$ might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\varphi(n)\leq n$ it follows that $$\frac{1}{\varphi(n)}\geq \frac{1}{n}$$ and hence $\sum \frac{1}{\varphi(n)}=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

A way of proof is the following:

$\dfrac{1}{p-1}\gt \dfrac1p$ and $\phi(p)=p-1$ then $$\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{\phi(n)}\gt\sum_{p\text { prime}}^N \dfrac{1}{\phi(p)}\gt\sum_{{p\text { prime}}}^N \dfrac{1}{p}\to \infty$$ (because of the Euler's proof of the infinity of primes).

Comment: He uses a stronger version : it's not just the infinity of primes itself, but Euler's proof of that result, which actually shows this sum diverges (so there cannot be a finite number of terms). The proof is not the full on Prime Number Theorem (you need Euler's product formula, and the fact that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \zeta(x) = +\infty$).

Comment: @N. S. Euler's proof does not assume that there are infinitely many primes but that the last sum above diverge so the set of primes is infinite.

Comment: @Joel Cohen.- Right. In fact many great results has been proved as a corollary of a strong theorem (even Fermat Last Theorem, the trascendence of $\pi$ and many others).